# ABP Framework - Extra properties foreign key lookup not working with angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, abp

ABP version: 5.3.3
Frontend: Angular
I'm trying to follow the same steps here https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.1/Module-Entity-Extensions#navigation-properties-foreign-keys
to get a lookup dropdown for an extra property called Bank Id but not working.

```
private static void ConfigureExtraProperties()
     {
         ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.Modules()
             .ConfigureIdentity(identity =>
             {
                 identity.ConfigureUser(user =>
                 {
                     user.AddOrUpdateProperty<Guid?>(
                         "BankId",
                          property =>
                          {
                              property.UI.Lookup.Url = "/api/banks";
                              property.UI.Lookup.DisplayPropertyName = "name";
                              property.UI.Lookup.ValuePropertyName = "id";
                          }
                         );
                 });
             });
     }
```

Here is the database mapping

```
public static void Configure()
    {
        CGCGlobalFeatureConfigurator.Configure();
        CGCModuleExtensionConfigurator.Configure();

        OneTimeRunner.Run(() =>
        {

            ObjectExtensionManager.Instance
                       .MapEfCoreProperty<IdentityUser, Guid?>(
                           "BankId",
                           (entityBuilder, propertyBuilder) =>
                           {
                               propertyBuilder.IsRequired(false);
                           }
                       );
        });
    }
```

Here is the API controller to just test it

```
[Route("api/banks")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BankController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ListResultDto<LookupDto>> GetAsync()
        {
            return new ListResultDto<LookupDto>(
                new[]
                {
                new LookupDto
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("6267f0df-870f-4173-be44-d74b4b56d2bd"),
                    Name = "Bank 1"
                },
                new LookupDto
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("21c7b61f-330c-489e-8b8c-80e0a78a5cc5"),
                    Name = "Production"
                }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Is this feature supported for angular?

Comment: Can you clarify how this relates to Angular? None of the code you've shown is TypeScript/Javascript.

Comment: From what I see `api/banks` is a webservice  returning an array. Angular can just call that webservice, read the array and build the dropdown from it. Once selected you call another webservice to get the data with the lookup id.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar it is abp framework and this configuration automatic binding to users component in angular

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I follow the steps here https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.1/Module-Entity-Extensions#navigation-properties-foreign-keys and if I change the api definition to be just an array of objects also the dropdown not appeared

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I'm following the same steps and I get a textbox with autocomplete instead of a dropdown (using v8.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue as this and I was able to resolve it by creating FormProp at frontend in addition to what you've implemented and also disabling the visibility of what you've implemented on the UI. Kindly look at the code below for more clarity on your implementation.

```
const branchProp = new FormProp<IdentityUserDto>({
type: ePropType.String,
name: 'branch',
displayName: 'AbpIdentity::Branch',
validators: () => [Validators.required],
isExtra: true,
options: data => {
    const service = data.getInjected(ApiService);
    return service.get('/api/endpoint-url')
      .pipe(
        map(({items}) => items.map(
          (item) => ({key: item.name, value: item.value })
        )),
      );
  }
});

export function branchPropContributor(propList: FormPropList<IdentityUserDto>) {
propList.addByIndex(branchProp, 4);
}
  export const identityCreateFormPropContributors: IdentityCreateFormPropContributors = {
// enum indicates the page to add contributors to
[eIdentityComponents.Users]: [
    branchPropContributor,
  // You can add more contributors here
],
};

export const identityEditFormPropContributors = identityCreateFormPropContributors;

// Add this to your routing code

path: 'privileges/manage', loadChildren: () => 
import('@abp/ng.identity').then(m => m.IdentityModule.forLazy(
        {
            createFormPropContributors: identityEditFormPropContributors,
            editFormPropContributors: identityEditFormPropContributors
        }
    ))

/* On the backend you should implement this in your IdentityDomainSharedModule which will add it as extra property value on your User table */

OneTimeRunner runner = new OneTimeRunner();
        runner.Run(()=>{
            ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.Modules()
                .ConfigureIdentity(identity =>
                {
                    identity.ConfigureUser(user =>
                    {
                        user.AddOrUpdateProperty<string>(
                            "branch",
                            property =>
                            {
                                property.UI.OnCreateForm.IsVisible = false;
                                property.UI.OnEditForm.IsVisible = false;   
                            }
                        );
                    });
                });
            });
```

N.B: Ensure that name value in Angular FormProp is the same as property name in your backend for my use case, its **branch**. Also ensure you set **IsExtra** to true in Angular FormProp so that the data will be added as extraproperties value in your Users table. I think you should know that I implemented this on Abp version 6.0.2 and Angular Cli 13.1.3